# Is possible to have a Composite Primary Key which components are entity foreign keys?

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have the following model:

```
(...)
@IdClass(BetID.class)           //Primary Key, composite = userID+gameID
public class Bet {

(...)
//Primary Key
@ManyToOne
    @Id
    private User user;          //Composite key:userID
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    private Game game;          //Composite key:gameID
```

In which, of course, has the following Composite key:

```
public class BetID implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    @OneToOne
    private Game game;
```

Here, User and Game are foreign keys, but also entities. Problem is when I'm trying to handle, so I can't set/get the key as easy as having a normal key like:
`@EmbeddedId BetID bet id` because the id has to refer 2 attributes from Bet. So using @Getter and @Setter (with lombok) is not possible.
So, how can I handle this? Is even possible to have a key like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a setter with two arguments:

```
public void setBetID(User user, Game game) {
   this.betId = new BetID(user, game);
}
```